# Mount a Windows network drive

Tags: linux, networking, mount, windows

I want to mount a network drive on the server (SBS2008). I have two options: Either using *Fedora*, (which already mounts on a *CentOS*) server, or directly on the *CentOS* server. Here is the command I tried on the *Fedora* machine:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.xx.xx/abc /mnt/lan -o username=usernameofwindowsmachine,pass=xyz
```

If I use this command nothing happens, and if I press *enter* it goes on to the next line and prints nothing.

I also tried to `mount` on the *CentOS* directly but no command worked (`mount -t smbfs`, `smbclient`, `smbmount`, ...). `smbmount` is not installed. `smbclient` gets a timeout and *Fedora* uses *cifs* and not *smbfs* ... The *Fedora* machine already has a mount on a *Windows 2003 Server*, but I don't know how this has been made. I don't want to install something because I only want to transfer a big file from *CentOS* to *SBS2008*.

**Edit**:
So it is not that easy to mount a network drive ... I went another way: I saw that *WinSCP* was installed on the *SBS2008* and connected on the machine and managed to transfer the file. The speed is not that good (1,8 MB/sec.) but hey it works.

Answer (score 5):

This must be:

```
     mount -t cifs //192.168.xx.xx/abc /mnt/lan -o username=usernameofwindowsmachine,password=xyz
```

Another approach is a credential file like `/root/.cifscredentials`:

```
     username=usernameofwindowsmachine
     password=xyz
```

and then use:

```
     mount -t cifs //192.168.xx.xx/abc /mnt/lan -o credentials=/root/.cifscredentials
```

Next should be using:

```
     mount -t cifs //WindowsDnsName/abc /mnt/lan -o credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,ip=192.168.xx.xx
```

Another thing is the *Windows Domain Name*, which can also be added to the `mount` options:

```
     mount -t cifs //WindowsDnsName/abc /mnt/lan -o credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,ip=192.168.xx.xx,domain=WinDomainName
```

After all that take a closer look at `man mount.cifs`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No matter what I tried I always got the same result (can enter text, go in the next line). How can I see the .cifscredential? It is not shown with `ls`.

Comment: If you use `ls -a` you should see the file. Because the filename starts with a dot it's hidden. Ich you user `cat /root/.cifscredentials` you will see the content of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Do you have an idea why the mount commands you posted do not work? And in `/home` I see a folder which mounts to a W2k3. How does the mount works there?

Comment: Some more information about "do not work" (error messages, etc) will help. On older systems the *old* smb mount is the default. On newer systems actual mount.cifs ist standard. You can check that with 'mount-cifs -V`.